# how to get quartiles and classify a value according to this quartile range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have this df:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Andres','Lars','Paul','Mike'],
                  'target':['A','A','B','C'],
                  'number':[10,12.3,11,6]})
```

And I want classify each number in a quartile.  I am doing this:

```
(d.groupby(['Name','target','number'])['number']
 .quantile([0.25,0.5,0.75,1]).unstack()
 .reset_index()
 .rename(columns={0.25:"1Q",0.5:"2Q",0.75:"3Q",1:"4Q"})
)
```

But as you can see, the 4 quartiles are all equal because the code above is calculating per row so if there's one 1 number per row all quartiles are equal.

If a run instead:

```
d['number'].quantile([0.25,0.5,0.75,1])
```

Then I have the 4 quartiles I am looking for:

```
0.25     9.000
0.50    10.500
0.75    11.325
1.00    12.300
```

**What I need as output(showing only first 2 rows)**

```
   Name    target   number     1Q      2Q      3Q        4Q     Rank
0   Andres  A       10.0       9.0    10.5    11.325    12.30     1
1   Lars    A       12.3       9.0    10.5    11.325    12.30     4
```

you can see all quartiles has the the values considering tall values in the `number` column.  Besides that, now we have a column names `Rank` that classify the number according to it's quartile.  ex.  In the first row 10 is within the 1st quartile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way that build on the quantiles you've created by making it a DataFrame and `join`ing it to `d`. Also `assign`s "Rank" column using `rank` method:

```
out = (d.join(d['number'].quantile([0.25,0.5,0.75,1])
              .set_axis([f'{i}Q' for i in range(1,5)], axis=0)
              .to_frame().T
              .pipe(lambda x: x.loc[x.index.repeat(len(d))])
              .reset_index(drop=True))
       .assign(Rank=d['number'].rank(method='dense')))
```

Output:

```
     Name target  number   1Q    2Q      3Q    4Q  Rank
0  Andres      A    10.0  9.0  10.5  11.325  12.3   2.0
1    Lars      A    12.3  9.0  10.5  11.325  12.3   4.0
2    Paul      B    11.0  9.0  10.5  11.325  12.3   3.0
3    Mike      C     6.0  9.0  10.5  11.325  12.3   1.0
```