# Why the rank function is not working when I set axis=1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have this code:

```
y=pd.DataFrame({'num':[10,12,13,11,14]})

out = (y.join(y['num'].quantile([0.25,0.5,0.75,1])
         .set_axis([f'{i}Q' for i in range(1,5)], axis=0)
         .to_frame().T       
         .pipe(lambda x: x.loc[x.index.repeat(len(y))])
       .reset_index(drop=True))
       .assign(Rank=y['num'].rank(method='first'))
)
```

The code is working as it is but is not returning What I want.  I was trying to rank `num` considering only it's row so

```
10 is rank 1 because 10 <= 1Q value
12 is rank 2 **(not 3)** because 2Q <= 12 < 3Q value
13 is rank 3 **(not 4)** because 3Q <= 13 < 4Q value
11 is rank 1 **(not 2)** because 1Q <= 11 < 2Q value
14 is rank 4 **(not 5)** because 14>= Q4
```

I tried to change this line:

```
.assign(Rank=y['num'].rank(method='first'))
```

to:

```
 .assign(Rank=y['num'].rank(axis=1,method='first'))
```

But it didn't work.

What am i missing here?

Comment: Btw, are you related to [this account](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71864830/17521785)? Your code is almost the same as my answer given there.

Comment: lol, katty is working with me in this project, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on what you already have here:

```
y = y.join(y['num'].quantile([0.25,0.5,0.75,1])
         .set_axis([f'{i}Q' for i in range(1,5)], axis=0)
         .to_frame().T       
         .pipe(lambda x: x.loc[x.index.repeat(len(y))])
       .reset_index(drop=True))
```

we could add the `Rank` column as follows. The idea is to compare the `num` column with the quantile columns and get the first column name where the quantile value is greater than a `num` value. As it happens each quantile column already has rank numbers on it, so we use those to assign values:

```
y['Rank'] = (y.drop(columns='num').ge(y['num'], axis=0)
             .pipe(lambda x: x*x.columns).replace('', pd.NA)
             .bfill(axis=1)['1Q'].str[0].astype(int))
```

Output:

```
   num    1Q    2Q    3Q    4Q  Rank
0   10  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0     1
1   12  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0     2
2   13  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0     3
3   11  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0     1
4   14  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0     4
```